# Why use iostream instead of ios in struct Io_guard from "The C++ Programming Language"?

Tags: c++

```
struct Io_guard { // RAII class for iostream exceptions
    iostream& s;
    auto old_e = s.exceptions();
    Io_guard(iostream& ss, ios_base::iostate e) :s{ss} { s.exceptions(s.exceptions()|e); }
    ˜Io_guard() { s.exceptions(old_e); }
};

void use(istream& is)
{
    Io_guard guard(is.ios_base::badbit);
    // ... use is ...
}
catch (ios_base::badbit) {
    // ... bail out! ...
}
```

Above code is from [4th edition of "The C++ Programming Language"](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), page 1080. I think it is better to do like

```
struct Io_guard {
    ios& s;
```

than

```
struct Io_guard {
    iostream &s;
```

because first one can be used to guard `istream`, `ostream`, and `iostream` since all of them are child classes of `ios`, but second one can only be used to guard `iostream`, since `istream` and `ostream` are not child classes of `iostream`.

Is Bjarne Stroustrup recommending to make three different Io_guards for each of `istream`, `ostream`, `iostream`?
Or is he just giving us an idea, so it is not important whether it is `iostream` or `ios`?

Comment: is this the code from the book literally? There is no constructor for `Io_guard guard(is.ios_base::badbit);`

Comment: The `catch` looks misplaced too

Comment: This book is already 8 years old...C++14 wasn't even released. I'm not sure it's up to date with the latest insights. We (even Bjarne probably) would chose to use a more generic approach now...

Comment: fwiw I found the example online here https://apprize.best/c/programming_2/38.html. It has the same issues. Consider that it is in a two level deep nested "for example..." and as you already suggested, I wouldn't take it too literally

Comment: Yeah, found it too... it's not a valid example... maybe written quickly? (And not even fixed for the 4th edition, or just added.) You can't catch a `badbit` as it's a value and not a type. It would probably even be a bad idea to throw the underlying `iostate` type, as it can be a fundamental type. You should wrap exceptions in proper exception types.

Comment: @JHBonarius • The book is still relevant.  C++11 was a major change.  C++14, 17, 20 are smaller (albeit still significant) evolutionary improvements.

Comment: @Eljay Although C++14 (and likely C++23) was a small release, C++17 and C++20 were very significant. The way we write C++ has significantly changed in the past 8 years (at least for us who can use the latest standards). There's likely some relevant information in the book, but a lot of other stuff is likely out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The code has more than one issue.

There is no constructor that would allow to create `Io_guard` via `Io_guard guard(is.ios_base::badbit);`. And the `catch` block is completely misplaced. `ios_base::badbit` is a `constexpr iostate`, ie not the type of an exception you can catch.

Given all this, I would not take the code too literally. Presumably it wasnt even meant as being ready to be used and compiled as is. Consider that it is in a section introduced via "For example ... For example...".  It merely demonstrates the general approach of how io exceptions can be handled by using a RAII wrapper.

---

The same example (same issues) can be found in an online 3rd edition version here: https://apprize.best/c/programming_2/38.html